# How do I bind complex IOptions?

Tags: asp.net-core

All of the primitive properties are bound correctly, but not the complex property `PagerOptions`, it's null.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "CommonAPISettings": {
    "Id": "I001",
    "Name": "Common.API",
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Orders;Application Name=Common.API",
    "PagerOptions": {
      "PageSize": 500,
      "MaxSize": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

**CommonAPISettings.cs**

```cs
public class CommonAPISettings
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public PagerSettings PagerSettings { get; set; }
}

public class PagerSettings
{
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int MaxSize { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.Configure<CommonAPISettings>(Configuration.GetSection("CommonAPISettings"));
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, JSON in your question is not valid (please apply better formatting in the future). I managed to fix it and noticed that in your model you have `PagerSettings` property, but in JSON it has name `PagingOptions`

```
{
  "CommonAPISettings": {
    "Id": "I001",
    "Name": "Common.API",
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Orders;Application Name=Common.API",
    "PagerSettings": {
      "PageSize": 500,
      "MaxSize": 1000
    }
  }
}
```